# JSON content fails to load due to cache in IE7 & IE8

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I know there is a cache problem with IE7 & IE8 when loading in JSON with AJAX, but I thought I had resolved that setting cache to false. The JSON in my page sometimes to fail to load only in those browsers. What could be wrong?

```
var language = "de";

$.ajax({
        url: "json/" + language + "/content.json",
        data: "nocache=" + Math.random(),
        type: "GET",
        cache : false,
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(source){
            data = source;
            showStartpage(data);
            showInfo(data);
        },
        error: function(data){
            alert("Failed to load content");
        }
    });
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I suppose it's not helpful to suggest you stop supporting IE7/8?  ;)

Comment: By sometimes it doesn't load, you also mean that sometimes it does load, am I correct?

Comment: Can you grab the underlying HTTP request and responses if any?